# Extract the first 8 bytes of an MD5 Hash

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm looking at taking a string and converting it to a Hash, I've been able to do this using the hashlib library with the following function

```
def get_md5_as_bytes(data):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(data)
    return m.digest()
```

What I need to do with the result of this is get the first 8 bytes of this string and then use it for something else.

In a previous question I was pointed to using Struct as a means of converting a 8 byte hex number to decimal and looking at it again I feel that it again is the solution to my problem. Is it possible to use a struct to extract the first 8 bytes from a byte string input?

Comment: Use slicing: `return m.digest()[:8]` / `return m.hexdigest()[:16]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following - basically splicing the return string using `[:8]` in the end

```
def get_md5_as_bytes(data):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(data)
    return m.hexdigest()[:8]
```

Note that I have used [hexdigest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/md5.html#md5.md5.hexdigest) instead of [digest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/md5.html#md5.md5.digest). You can revert the same if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [mu 無](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1860929/mu-%e7%84%a1) solution with `m.hexdigest()[:8]` then you can convert it into list of bytes:

```
hex_str = get_md5_as_bytes('hello world')

print 'string:', hex_str

bytes = [ int(x, 16) for x in hex_str ]

print 'bytes:', bytes
```

result

```
string: 5eb63bbb
bytes: [5, 14, 11, 6, 3, 11, 11, 11]
```

---

**EDIT:**

Using

```
import struct

print 'unpack:', struct.unpack('8B', hex_str)
```

you could get ascii code of chars in `hex_str` - but I think it isn't what you expect.

```
string: 5eb63bbb
unpack: (53, 101, 98, 54, 51, 98, 98, 98)
```

but maybe using it with `m.digest()` you get what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody want to get an int64:

```
def hash_int64(input_string):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(input_string)
    bytes_64 = m.digest()[:8]
    return struct.unpack('>q', bytes_64)[0]
```

Based on [mu 無](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1860929/mu-%E7%84%A1)'s answer